# Чтение локального файла средствами JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Сразу прошу тапками не кидаться - честно гуглил, но адекватного ответа не нашел...

Мне нужно считать указанный пользователем файл (с локальной машины конечно же) именно в JavaScript. [Задача такая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207178/javascript-%D1%81%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-jszip), а не моя фантазия...

Вроде бы это можно сделать средствами [***HTML5 (File API)***](http://true-coder.ru/javascript/chitaem-fajly-raspolozhennye-lokalno-pri-pomoshhi-javascript.html), и кстати нормально так делается...
Но вездесущий *IE* как всегда все портит, а потому нужна альтернатива как минимум для него, ибо он ***File API*** до сих пор не поддерживает...
Конечно же, в идеале, нужна кроссбраузерная альтернатива, если такая имеется...

Собственно в этом и весь вопрос к вам, знатоки... в альтернативе...

Comment: без fileapi - только флэш/java. но я бы просто сделал - те кто fileapi поддерживают используют его, а те кто нет. по-старинке POST

Comment: Может, костыль: слать файл на свой сервер, и оттуда уже отдавать юзеру?

Comment: давайте ещё будем учитывать, что не вездесущий IE, а вездесущие IE<10. IE10+ прекрасно поддерживает File API - http://caniuse.com/fileapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кусок кода можно добавить "в лоб" - через src. Просто не забывайте, что вы там прописали. Например, в текстовом файле может находиться переменная вида:

```
var имя="строка"; (можно без "var" и ";")
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script src="myfile.txt" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<!-- Содержимое файла "myfile.txt": 'stroke="My text."' -->
Значение переменной "stroke": <script>document.write(stroke);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для IE - ActiveXObject не ?

```
var inp = document.getElementById('myFile');

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var f = fso.OpenTextFile(inp.value, 1);

while (!f.AtEndOfStream) {
    var r = f.ReadLine();
    document.write (r + "<br />");
}

f.Close();
```

Comment: А для не текстовых файлов разве этот метод подходит ?

Answer (score 2):

Ребята! Не знаю, тема актуальна ещё или нет, но я нашел решение!
На сайте [CodePen](http://codepen.io) был один проект, где загружалась SVG картинка и там парсилась. Спёр код оттуда.

```js
function readFile(object) {
  var file = object.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = reader.result
  }
  reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<button onclick="readFile(document.getElementById('file'))">Read!</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Вот как-то так. Можете посмотреть на [CodePen](http://codepen.io/NoNickName/pen/gmZdZj) версию

- читает ВСЕ файлы

Answer (score 0):

Зачем HTML5 ?

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'filename.dat',
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data); // Выведет содержимое файла в консоль
      }
});
```

Если просто нужно получить инфу из файла - теоретически должно работать, ведь .json файлы парсятся без проблем.

Comment: речь про кнопочку "выберите файл"

Comment: Мне не с сервера нужно получить файл, а прочитать выбранный пользователем файл(-ы) в  

    <input type="file" multiple="true" />

Это сделать на чистом JS, на сколько я знаю, нельзя, потому я и спрашиваю...

Comment: Раз знаете, то зачем спрашиваете?

Answer (score 0):

JS такого не поддерживает.
HTML5 это действительно поддерживает и скоро даже IE этому научится - подождите годик другой...
Если нужно раньше, то ActiveX, а для старых версий браузера только Flash.

Как говорится, большего не дано. Браузер изначально ограничен в этом плане.
По конкретным решения гугл вас в помощь, так как вы не сказали какими инструментами пользуетесь - чистым JS, или нет...